# Пересчет из метров в секундах в километры в час

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!

Пишу простенькую программу, я её раньше писал, но слетел жёсткий, а диск прилогаемый к самоучителю Никита Культин (Delphi  в задачах и примерах) сломался пополам, исходники в книжке есть, только не могу разобраться, куда что.

Задача программы пересчитать скорость ветра из "метров в секунды" в "километров в час". 
У меня возникают ошибки. Вот исходник:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin;
ms: integer; // skorost m/s
kmh: real; // ckorost km/chias

end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
ms:= StrToint (Edit1.Text); // ВВести исходные данные
kmh: = ms * 3.6; // пересчитать
// вывести результат
labal1.caption :=
intToStr(kmh) + 'km/час'
end;

end.
```

Comment: Какие именно ошибки у вас возникают? Для этого примера нужно создать форму с полем ввода и кнопкой. И назначить кнопке обработчик.  Дальше проблем не должно быть.

Comment: Просто пишите всё очень внимательно, соблюдая регистр и буквы, как в учебнике и как объявлено.

Comment: спс

Answer (score 4):

Вы вызываете `intToStr(kmh)`, в то время, как переменная `kmh` относится к типу `real`.
Воспользуйтесь для преобразования `FloatToStr`.

Да, и кусок

```
ms: integer; // skorost m/s
kmh: real; // ckorost km/chias
```

нужно перенести в `var`-секцию процедуры, в которой они используются (`Edit1Change`).

И в `labal1.caption` у вас опечатка.

В общем вот так:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms: integer; // skorost m/s
  kmh: real; // ckorost km/chias
begin
  ms:= StrToint (Edit1.Text); // ВВести исходные данные
  kmh: = ms * 3.6; // пересчитать
  // вывести результат
  label1.caption :=
  FloatToStr(kmh) + 'km/час'
end;
```

Comment: Тогда уж и скорость лучше real сделать.

Answer (score 2):

```
labal1.caption
```

надо заменить на

```
Label1.caption
```

p.s. в вопросе указывайте ошибки, чтоб не гадать на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ Nofate +1, все верно.
Но можно, а иногда просто нужно добавить фильтр для ввода значений. Вероятность ввода не корректных данных резко снижается.
Событие KeyPress на Edit

```
//проверка введеных симоволов - ФИЛЬТР!
//все символы хранятся в Key!

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin

case key of
//#8 = BackSpace
'0'..'9',#8:;    //пропускаем символы в едит!
'.',',':
        begin
             key:=decimalSeparator;
             //если подстрока в строке есть, то пишем пустой символ!!!
             if pos(decimalSeparator,edit1.text)<>0 then
                                                  key:=Char(0)
        else
            key:=char(0); // остальные символы, нет!!!
        end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Всем спасибо классный сай тик по программированию, ща опробую коды.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант:

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Spin, Mask;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure Edit3KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

uses AboutUnit;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ms, resultkms: real;
begin
ms:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
resultkms:=ms*3.6;
Edit2.Text:=FloatToStr(resultkms);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var resultms, kms: real;
begin
kms:=StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
resultms:=kms/3.6;
Edit4.Text:=FloatToStr(resultms);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
MainForm.Close;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
AboutForm.Show;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);

var ms, resultkms: real;

begin
    case Key of
  #8,'0'..'9' :  ; // цифры, <Back Space> и <Enter>

       '.',',': // разделитель целой и дробной частей числа
                begin
                  if Key <> DecimalSeparator then
                  Key := DecimalSeparator; // заменим разделитель на допустимый
                  if Pos(DecimalSeparator,Edit1.Text) <> 0 then
                  Key := Chr(0); // запрет ввода второго разделителя
                 end;
           '-':    // минус можно ввести только первым символом,
                // т.е. когда ячейка пустая
                if Length(Edit1.Text) <> 0
                      then Key := Chr(0);
            #13:   if Key = #13 then
                   begin
                   ms:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
                   resultkms:=ms*3.6;
                   Edit2.Text:=FloatToStr(resultkms);
                   end;
        else   // остальные символы запрещены
               key := Chr(0);
               ShowMessage('Ну кто вводит текст в поле для цифр?!'+#13#10+'Введите цифры!');

    end;       // case
end;           //begin

procedure TMainForm.Edit3KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var kms, resultms: real;
begin
case Key of
  #8,'0'..'9' :  ; // цифры и <Back Space>

       '.',',': // разделитель целой и дробной частей числа
                begin
                  if Key <> DecimalSeparator then
                  Key := DecimalSeparator; // заменим разделитель на допустимый
                  if Pos(DecimalSeparator,Edit3.Text) <> 0
                  then Key := Chr(0); // запрет ввода второго разделителя
                end;
           '-':    // минус можно ввести только первым символом,
                // т.е. когда ячейка пустая
                if Length(Edit3.Text) <> 0
                      then Key := Chr(0);
            #13:   if Key = #13 then
                   begin
                   kms:=StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
                   resultms:=kms/3.6;
                   Edit4.Text:=FloatToStr(resultms);
                   end;
        else   // остальные символы запрещены
               key := Chr(0);
               ShowMessage('Ну кто вводит текст в поле для цифр?!'+#13#10+'Введите цифры!');

    end;       // case
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Выкиньте Культина. Он вас ничему не научит.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/48046)

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, я бы не стал удалять.